# Strange highlighting in LaTeX-Suite

Tags: editors, highlighting, vim-latex

I use Vim 7.3 and LaTeX-Suite 1.8.23.

But every time when I use the function in LaTeX-Suite , such as `$e^^` and `amsmath<F5>`, the whole source code will be highlighted. How to fix it up?

[image: All be highlighted]